# How would VirtualAlloc enhance .Net application's performance?

Tags: c#, performance, winapi, memory-management

I saw some uses of the VirtualAlloc/Free windows API methods in some C# applications and I was wondering for the cause of using these methods in C#.

What would VirtualAlloc/Free would benefit for me, any ideas?

**EDIT**: Would VirtualAlloc perform better than typical .Net "new" statement or any other .Net memory allocation methods?

Comment: what does MSDN say about what VirtualAlloc/Free does.. have you done a google search..?

Comment: here is a good link to check Reserving and Committing Memory
[1]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I know what VirtualAlloc/Free is, my question is regarding the benefit of using it for .Net development.

Comment: What benefit are you looking for? Also, could you give an example of some code that uses it? We could maybe then understand why. This Q feels like,"what is the problem that needs this solution?" which is a bit broad.

Comment: This appears to be an overly broad and open-ended question. Maybe you should ask about specific examples that yo have seen.

Comment: Of course it already uses it.  Any Windows program that allocates memory uses it.  No point in asking "can it do better?", that's been heavily weighed over already.

Comment: "Would VirtualAlloc perform better than typical .Net "new" statement or any other .Net memory allocation
methods?" You need to be more precise. For a start the two operations you are comparing are very different. They are not even remotely interchangeable. It's like asking if Quicksort performs better than bisection.

Comment: Both of them allocates memory, .Net allocation will be handled with the GC at some point and Windows API allocation will not - it sounds pretty similar to me or did I miss something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only benefit that I see is that size of the single managed object is limited to 2GB. If you use `VirtualAlloc/VirtualFree` you can manage bigger objects. At the same time I would recommend you using NT heaps (`HeapAlloc/HeapFree`) for this purpose.

Read about memory states: committed/reserved/free. You can use them in virtual allocations. In some rare cases they are useful.

Answer (score 1):

One scenario that requires the use of the VirtualAllocEx is when you need to allocate memory in the address space of a different process.   I cannot imagine any other use case for VirtualAllocEx or VirtualAlloc in a managed app.

Comment: Right, but VirtualAlloc and VirtualAllocEx are different APIs.

Comment: @KirillKobelev Indeed, but closely related. I can't see any need for `VirtualAlloc` at all since `AllocHGlobal` has all you need if you just need a >2GB block. And if you must use native APIs then `HeapAlloc` is the one. So I'm guessing that the code Eran refers to actually uses `VirtualAllocEx` and he/she has remembered that detail incorrectly.

Comment: My guess that the only use of VitrualAlloc (not VirtualAllocEx) is if you want to write our own heap or something similar. Once a while this happens.

Comment: @Kirill That's odd given that you said something else in your answer

Comment: Well, yes and no. Something that uses committed/reserved, is it't it look like a heap? p.s. For allocation >2gb you still should use HeapAlloc. For me `VirtualAllocEx` is something only for injecting dll. Do you know any other use?

Comment: @KirillKobelev Or `AllocHGlobal`. I guess I didn't interpret your answer correctly. When you said "The only benefit that I see is that size of the single managed object is limited to 2GB." I guess I should have interpreted that as "The only benefit that I see is to write your own heap."  ;-)

Comment: can you imagine application that needs only one allocation >2gb? This is already close to a heap manager. I do not insist that all my statements are absolutely perfect.